# How to send string value from activity to asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have IzborKategorija.java activity where upon user's checkbox choices creating STRING which i need to send to asyncTask as last part of url I using to make GET method. So, I create STRING like: 3,6,7,9 and I need to append this string to "http://www.example.com/push/?device_token="+regid+"&channels_ids="+STRINGFROMACTIVITY.
My AsyncTask already waiting registration from GCM, and how to add one more parameter there?

My activity IzborKategorija.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IzborKategorija extends Activity{
    ListView myList;
    Button getChoice, clearAll;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyUserChoice" ;
    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static final String TAG = "KATARINA";
    String savedItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        getChoice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getchoice);
        clearAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clearall);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Mobile_OS));
        myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sharedpreferences.contains(MyPREFERENCES)){
            LoadSelections();
        }

        getChoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String selected = "";
                int cntChoice = myList.getCount();

                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){
                    if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                        selected += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
                        System.out.println("Checking list while adding:" + myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        SaveSelections();
                    }

                }


                Toast.makeText(IzborKategorija.this, selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }});

        clearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ClearSelections();
            }
        });


    }

    private void SaveSelections() {
// save the selections in the shared preference in private mode for the user

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        String savedItems = getSavedItems();
        prefEditor.putString(MyPREFERENCES.toString(), savedItems);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }

    private String getSavedItems() {
        String savedItems = "";
        int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (this.myList.isItemChecked(i)) {
                if (savedItems.length() > 0) {
                    savedItems += "," + this.myList.getItemAtPosition(i);
                } else {
                    savedItems += this.myList.getItemAtPosition(i);
                }
            }
        }

        savedItems = savedItems.replaceAll("[^0-9,]", "");
        Log.i(TAG, "SPISAK ODABRANIH: " + savedItems);
        return savedItems;


    }


    private void LoadSelections() {
// if the selections were previously saved load them

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(MyPREFERENCES.toString())) {

            String savedItems = sharedpreferences.getString(MyPREFERENCES.toString(), "");
            selectedItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));

            int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String currentItem = (String) myList.getAdapter()
                        .getItem(i);
                if (selectedItems.contains(currentItem)) {
                    myList.setItemChecked(i, true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Curren Item: " + currentItem,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    myList.setItemChecked(i, false);
                }

            }
        }
    }

   private void ClearSelections() {
// user has clicked clear button so uncheck all the items
        int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            this.myList.setItemChecked(i, false);
        }
// also clear the saved selections
        SaveSelections();
    }

}
```

My AsyncTask RegisterApp.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RegisterApp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

 private static final String TAG = "GCMRelated";
 Context ctx;
 GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
 String SENDER_ID = "980800840437";
 String regid = null;
 private int appVersion;
 public RegisterApp(Context ctx, GoogleCloudMessaging gcm, int appVersion){
  this.ctx = ctx;
  this.gcm = gcm;
  this.appVersion = appVersion;
 }


 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
  super.onPreExecute();
 }


 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


     String msg = "";
        try {
            if (gcm == null) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(ctx);
            }
            regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
            msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

            // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
            // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
            // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
            // is using accounts.
            sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

            // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
            // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
            // message using the 'from' address in the message.

            // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
            storeRegistrationId(ctx, regid);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
            // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
            // exponential back-off.
        }
        return msg;

 }


 private void storeRegistrationId(Context ctx, String regid) {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
             Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
     editor.putString("registration_id", regid);
     editor.putInt("appVersion", appVersion);
     editor.commit();

 }




    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() throws IOException {

        URL obj = new URL("http://www.example.com/push/?device_token="+regid+"&channels_id="+STRINGFROMACTIVITY);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());

            Log.i(TAG, "OVO SAM POSLAO " + savedItems);

        } else {
            System.out.println("GET request not worked");
        }

    }



 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  super.onPostExecute(result);
  Toast.makeText(ctx, "Registration Completed. Now you can see the notifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Log.v(TAG, result);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `STRINGFROMACTIVITY` from the Activity to AsyncTask in the constructor.
For eg:
In your activity,

```
new RegisterApp(STRINGFROMACTIVITY).execute();
```

In the AsycnTask(RegisterApp) constructor,

```
String STRINGFROMACTIVITY;  //create string variable in RegisterApp
......
......

public RegisterApp(String STRINGFROMACTIVITY){
  this.STRINGFROMACTIVITY= STRINGFROMACTIVITY;
 }
```

Looking at your code, I see you already have 3 parameters being passed from Activity to Asyctask like `Context ctx, GoogleCloudMessaging gcm, int appVersion`, now the string value should be the fourth one to be passed.
Also your `AsyncTask` should have these 4 parameters to be passed.

Comment: @Ranjith - I did all thing you said, this added to my activity "new RegisterApp(STRINGFROMACTIVITY).execute();" and give me error expected parameters (ctx, gcm, int Appversion, String) Actual arguments (android.Context.context STRINGFROMACTIVITY java.lang.String). And I did constructor in Asynctask, but what to add in doInBackground? thanks!

Comment: @DanielNugent what should I insert in doInBackground? My String?

Comment: @bladimir I had updated my answer..Accidently i had put it in execute(). Just refer to the answer

Comment: sorry Ranjith, but how to see your updated answer, I'm new on stackoverflow, did you make any changes to your earlier answer for my problem? If you do, how to see those changes, it is very important to me to solve this problem, project is waiting!

Comment: Whatever answer you see now is updated one, just follow that

Comment: I did again same stuff you said and this is a error I received from my activity class: http://i60.tinypic.com/34gxevq.jpg